# Possible Bug in Chrome loading jQuery script on document.ready

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I want to execute the following script

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#deckblatt').offset().top
}, 1)
```

deckblatt is the first content-div on my page.

Chrome won't do this, but FF would.

The confusing part is that i've got the same excent method running on a second page, which works perfectly fine on both Chrome and FF.

What have i missed or is there maybe a better way to do what i want to achieve, preventing the browser from automatically jumping to a section of the page when it was scrolled down before?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is the complete code for the first project, which is not running correctly

[sprottenwels](http://sprottenwels.net/Bewerbung/)

And here is the code of the second one, which works fine

[#2](http://antaw.de/RM/scroll.html)

Comment: I think you should rather use jQuery scrollTo plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it. But neverless, i still would like to know why this is not working.

Comment: I'm getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined" for `if (target == "#top"){$('.scroll-top').hide() ;}` in Chrome. Looks like you don't use the class `.scroll-top` anywhere in your HTML. Also, works the same for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Sprottenwels: you're welcome. Since then, I inspected the source of your problem a little bit deeper, and [I posted the possible reasons as a detailed answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14184381/517705). Please look at that, and give me some feedback whether you understood the source of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Chrome bug. Your [original code](http://jsfiddle.net/uKcQG) contains some strange stuffs.

- You don't have any elements with `scroll-top` class, which should be shown when scrolling down, and which the user could click on to scroll to the top.
- You don't have any elements with `top` or `bottom` id like in the other one.
- You left out some [needed CSS codes](http://antaw.de/RM/stylesheets/scroll.css) from the JSFiddle-code which you do have in the other working example.
- But one of the **most important** errors: `target` variable is undefined in your JavaScript code, and you inspect its equality with "#top" string. This leads to a ReferenceError exception. I think you wanted to inspect whether the click event's target element's id is equal to the `"#top"` string. For this, you should declare e.g. the `event` argument in the event handler, and use `event.target.id`.
  So instead of this:

  ```
  $('.scroll').click(function(){

      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this.id).offset().top
      }, 500);

      setTimeout("$('.scroll-top').fadeIn();",510 );

      if (target == "#top"){$('.scroll-top').hide() ;}

  });
  ```

  You should use this code:

  ```
  $('.scroll').click(function(event) { // declaring event variable as an argument
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this.id).offset().top
      }, 500);

      // inspecting the id of the click event's target element
      if (event.target.id == "#top") {
        $('.scroll-top').hide();
      } 
      else {
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('.scroll-top').fadeIn();
        }, 510);
      }

  });
  ```

I modified your [original code](http://jsfiddle.net/uKcQG), uncommenting very much unneeded stuffs, but there are still many left:

http://jsfiddle.net/uKcQG/3/

It's still a little buggy, but now the scrolling seems to work correctly.

But as I suggested in my comment, **you should definitely use Ariel Flesler's *jQuery scrollTo plugin* for this task: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/**

Comment: Thank you very much, i totally ruined this one, still using the above said plugin. I'm accepting this :)

Comment: @Sprottenwels: I'm glad I could help, you're welcome! :) It's also good to hear that the scrollTo plugin gives you what you need!